# Unable to resolve some modules: meteor npm install --save eventEmitter

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I run my meteor app I get error in npm module "eventEmitter" but I am tring add npm package eventEmitter no any eventEmitter package in npm.

So how to add eventEmitter package in my meteor app.

This is my error:

```js
=> Meteor server restarted

Unable to resolve some modules:

  "eventEmitter" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/client/lib/plugins/core.min.js (web.browser)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save eventEmitter
```

How can I resolve this?